# What JVM can run on CPU and GPU?

Tags: java

What JVM runs on a CPU + GPU?

I know JVM like *Oracle*, *Zulu*, *OpenJDK* but none is designed to offload processing to  GPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one, https://www.tornadovm.org/ but not sure how mature.

TornadoVM can currently execute on multi-core CPUs, dedicated GPUs (Nvidia, AMD), integrated GPUs (Intel HD Graphics and ARM Mali), and FPGAs (Intel and Xilinx).

```
Backend wise (not all OSes support all these):
--opencl: Enables the OpenCL backend (requires OpenCL drivers)
--ptx: Enables the PTX backend (requires NVIDIA CUDA drivers)
--spirv: Enables the SPIRV backend (requires Intel Level Zero drivers)
```